# Do you use "there is" or "there are" before a list?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

When I use "there are:" (with a colon) to introduce a list starting with a singular item, should I use "there is" or "there are"?

According to grammar rules, I should use "there is" if the following item is singular, but in this case the colon introduces a plural group.

For example:

> In my room **there [is/are]:** a bed, 2 chairs, a table, 2 carpets and a wardrobe.

Answer (score 3):

You could rearrange your list to start with the plural items first and end with the singular items in which case "there are" would be the correct choice:

> ... there are: 2 chairs, 2 carpets, a bed and a wardrobe

Comment: I think one could also remove the colon, but if you insist on doing a list, I agree with you.